# Magento Division By Zero Warning PHP

Tags: magento-1.9, php, theme, log

I am getting a division by zero warning in my log file from this snippet of text in my Magento theme:

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i-0)%$_columnCount==0): ?>  last1<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last1<?php endif; ?>">
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thank you!

---

Here is the whole page of code:

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM
);
?>
<?php if ($_columnCount) { ?>
<li class="item<?php if(($i-0)%$_columnCount==0): ?> last1<?php 
elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last1<?php endif; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<div class="item-inner">
<?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(70, 85)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="70" height="85" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(70, 85)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="70" height="85" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="product-details">

 <div class="access">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove1"><?php echo $this->__('Remove') ?></a>
    <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item') ?>" class="btn-edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i><span class="hidden"><?php echo $this->__('Edit item')?></span></a>
    <?php endif ?>
 </div> <!--access-->

<strong><?php echo $this->getQty() ?></strong> x

<?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>

    <span class="map-cart-sidebar-item"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>

<?php else: ?>

<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
        <br />
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
            <small>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </small>
        <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
            <small>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </small>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
            <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>



<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
    <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <br /><?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
        <br />
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
            <small>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </small>
        <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
            <small>
            <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </small>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
            <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; //Can apply MSRP ?>

    <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
    <div class="truncated">
      <div class="truncated_full_value">
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
      </div>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

 <p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php $prod_name= $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()); if(strlen($prod_name) > 35) { echo substr($prod_name,0,35)."..."; } else { echo $prod_name; } ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>

</div> <!--product-details-bottoms-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    <?php if ($_columnCount) { ?>
    <li class="item<?php if(($i-0)%$_columnCount==0): ?>  last1<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last1<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li class="item">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So it works, but for some reason I can't scroll the page with my mouse roller. My mouse scroll works when I disable it.

Comment: Try the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$_columnCount` is zero at some point and modulo (the `%` operator) on 0 is illegal behaviour as you're essentially asking for the remainder of a zero divison.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would I have to adjust any of the numbers to make this work and what would I change them too?